# How to use json_encode to return as json based my code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Here, I want to encode php return in json output.I'm so confused to implement on there. So, how the correct way I have to do.

index.html

```
    $(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "profile.php", 
            success: function(resp){
                var username = JSON.parse(resp).username;
                var profile = JSON.parse(resp).profile;
                $('.test').html(username+profile );

            }
         });
       });
```

profile.php

```
<?php
  require_once('class.php');
?>

<?php    
if ($user->is_logged == 1) {
    $txtuser = '';
    if (empty($D->me->firstname)) $txtuser = $D->me->username;
    else $txtuser = $D->me->firstname;

    if (empty($D->me->avatar)) $txtavatar = 'default.jpg';
    else $txtavatar = $D->me->avatar;
}
?>

<?php
 echo json_encode(array('username' => '{$C->SITE_URL.$D->me->username}', 'profile' => '{$txtuser}' ));
?>
```

Comment: will `$C->SITE_URL.$D->me->username` and `$txtuser` always be a string?

Comment: remove all useless <?php ?>

Comment: output when I use php as return data is username : "http://localhost/data/johnmike" , profile : "John"

Comment: Use double quotes and you will not have to bother encasing the variables in `{ }`

Comment: so they are both string. If they are both string, and you are using `json_encode`, you should not be getting errors. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean it out this way, and let me know if you still have issues:

```
<?php
  require_once('class.php');

  if ($user->is_logged == 1) {
    $txtuser = '';
    if (empty($D->me->firstname)) $txtuser = $D->me->username;
    else $txtuser = $D->me->firstname;

    if (empty($D->me->avatar)) $txtavatar = 'default.jpg';
    else $txtavatar = $D->me->avatar;
  }

  $arr = array(
     "username" => $C->SITE_URL . $D->me->username,
     "profile" => $txtuser
  );

  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

in your Ajax response use `console.log(resp)` to see any errors in the console.

Comment: Oh,thanks @CodeGodie, I have tried,but got error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: but, in ajax function of my code is correct way to response?

Comment: I'm givin you downvote becouse you did not provide any effort to explain your answer, it is plain copy-paste of invalid code in question with string concatenation inside curly syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) option to `json`, that way you will tell the jQuery that the data expected from the server is in JSON format, and jQuery will try to convert a JSON string into an object. It is not necessary manually do that with `JSON.parse()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "profile.php",
    dataType: 'json',           
    success: function( resp ){          
        console.log( resp );
    }
});
```

Use `console.log()` to inspect the result ( [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) ).

Another thing is that you should remove the quotation marks and just concatenate strings with dot ( PHP [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) ). Also, there should not be any output before and after `json_encode()` because it will break json string, su just use [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php).

```
die( json_encode( array( 'username' => $C->SITE_URL . $D->me->username, 'profile' => $txtuser ) ) );
```

Comment: thanks @Danijel,so how to get username and profile instead using json.parse()?

Comment: @CodeGodie, thanks for downvote too, i hope you're feeling better now.